# unable to install tensorflow using pip on windows

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

i have tried the whl file also but the every time same error pops up

```
-> pip install tensorflow
```

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for tensorflow

```
->pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

> tensorflow-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: What python version do you have installed?

Comment: Also, why are you trying to install tensorflow **0.12.1**  when the currently released version is 1.3 (and it's *very* different in many, many ways from the old 0.12)?

Comment: python 3.6.2 @GPhilo

Comment: As i was unable to install tersorflow using pip i tried using whl which also failed @GPhilo

Comment: The wheel you're trying to install is compiled for python 3.5 (that's what the **cp35** means in the file name). Try this: [https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.3.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl](https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.3.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl)

Comment: tensorflow-1.3.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: Is your Windows installation a 64bit one?

Comment: windows 7 64 bit @GPhilo

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. I just tried the wheel I linked you and I don't have any problems installing it on python 3.6 + Windows, so I think you might have something wrong in your setup. What's the result of `pip --version`?

Comment: the version of pip is 9.0.1 @GPhilo

Comment: Please paste the *full* output of the command

Comment: just changed the version to python 3.5 and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Re-installation of python with 3.5 version fixed all errors

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking all over the interwebs, and I see dropping from v3.6 to v3.5 to be the most suggested workaround for this.  However, The [tensorflow site](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) says this:

> TensorFlow supports Python 3.5.x and 3.6.x on Windows. Note that
>   Python 3 comes with the pip3 package manager, which is the program
>   you'll use to install TensorFlow.

I can't seem to get 3.6 to work.  Anyone know if 3.6 is now actually supported, or is that possible fake news on the tensorflow site?

Answer (score 0):

@kghastie I installed TensorFlow with Python 3.6 on windows machine.

Able to run premade-estimators successfully from their documentation

If you two python version 2x and 3x, rename both appropriately and run the install command using

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```